# How should I enable my terminal find command on the whole disk on macOS 10.13.6?

Tags: macos

I am using macOS 10.13.6, on which, `sudo find / -name` always gets "Operation not permitted".

I googled it and got some "solution" which needs me enable "Full Disk Access".

However, "Security & Privacy" panel doesn't have an item called "Full Disk Access".

[image]

How should I enable my terminal find command on the whole disk?

Comment: In 10.13, it already is. You’re applying  10.15 security & privacy technologies to a version that doesn’t have it.   What is the issue you’re having?

Comment: Probably use `sudo find ...`

Answer (score 3):

Make some tea and you’re done. That setting won’t arrive until you upgrade to a newer OS.

Your find command has no barriers other than traditional ACL and permissions to stop it from traversing the entire disk.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-permissions-for-files-folders-or-disks-mchlp1203/mac